NIOSocket write not sending data
first of all thank to everyone who will try to help. I am struggling with a strange problem on our server and the situation is very critical now: we have peripherials opening sockets and writing authentications and the server verifying them and answering ACK or NACK. Everything was properly working until few weeks ago (but the number of peripherials communicating was really low, let's say <10). In the last weeks, when the number of peripherials has grown up to 40 (but I can't be sure the problem is related to that), everything stopped working: the peripherials stopped receiving the answers from server.
The problem is that even if the write function of socket channel returns the correct amount as bytes written, the data don't get sent. We tried to check it with a tcpdump that shown as the only packets going are the TCP control packets for open/close socket and the incoming data paclets.
Note: if we just open a socket and send an authentication with hercules, we from time to time succeed to receive an answer when we push the "disconnect" button. This seems to suggest that the bytes we want to send are somewhere inside a buffer that is not flushed until the socket is closed, but as far as I understood reading around, niosocket write should write directly to OS socket. Is there a buffer at that level maybe?
What we tried to far:

standard channel.write
a while(buffer.hasremaining > 0) channel.write(buffer) solution that we have found over the net, but that I think it's incorrect and in fact it doesn't work.
We tried to put a buffer.flip() after the write, but it didn't help (and it shouldn't, as we use freshly allocated bytebuffer at every write).

A bit of our code, even if it is pretty standard:
public NIOSocketServer(int port) throws IOException {
    this.port = port;
    listenAddress = new InetSocketAddress(this.port);
}

public void initialize() throws IOException {
    this.setPriority(this.thread_priority);

    this.selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false); 

    // retrieve server socket and bind to port  serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddress,this.max_pending_connection_queue); 
    serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    String status;

    running.set(true);

    status = getStatus();
    log.info("=".repeat(status.length()));
    log.info(status);
    log.info("=".repeat(status.length()));

    while (running.get()) {
    try {
            // wait for events
            selector.select(1000L); //1000L
            // work on selected keys
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();
                // this is necessary to prevent the same key from coming up
                // again the next time around.
                keys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    this.process(key);
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.process(key);
                }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL_MS_MEDIUM);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    status = getStatus();
}

private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
    channel.configureBlocking(false);

    /* -> setTcpNoDelay */
    try {
        channel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(this.tcp_no_delay);      // set to true
    } catch (SocketException e){
        log.error("UNABLE to set TCP_NO_DELAY to NIO socket on local port " + channel.socket().getLocalPort() + " from " + channel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress() + "...");
    }

    /* -> setTrafficClass */
    if (OS.isNIX()) {
        if (this.iptos != 0x00){
            try {
                channel.socket().setTrafficClass(this.iptos);
            } catch (SocketException e){
                log.error("UNABLE to set IPTOS to NIO socket on local port " + channel.socket().getLocalPort() + " from " + channel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress() + "...");
            }
        } else {
            log.info("IPTOS DISABLED to NIO socket on local port " + channel.socket().getLocalPort() + " from " + channel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress() + "...");
        }
    }

    /* -> setReceiveBuffer */
    try {
        channel.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(this.so_rcvbuf);
    } catch (SocketException e){
        log.error("UNABLE to set SO_RCVBUF to NIO socket on local port " + channel.socket().getLocalPort() + " from " + channel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress() + "...");
    }

    /* -> setSendBuffer */
    try {
        channel.socket().setSendBufferSize(this.so_rcvbuf);
    } catch (SocketException e){
        log.error("UNABLE to set SO_SNDBUF to NIO socket on local port " + channel.socket().getLocalPort() + " from " + channel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress() + "...");
    }
    // register channel with selector for further IO

    // registro una nuova sessione al channel socket appena aperto...
    SelectionKey readKey = channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, ByteBuffer.allocate(this.getSoRcvBuf()));
    readKey.attach(new ActiveCmeDeviceSession(channel,this.selector,
                                                      this.save_to_log_enabled)); //save to log in base alle proprietà della server socket
}

private void process(SelectionKey key) {
    ActiveCmeDeviceSession activeCmeDeviceSession = (ActiveCmeDeviceSession) key.attachment();

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(this.so_rcvbuf);
    byte[] raw_data;

    int numRead = -1;
    numRead = activeCmeDeviceSession.read(byteBuffer);
    byteBuffer.flip(); 

    if (key!= null && key.isValid()){
        key.interestOps(key.interestOps() | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        selector.wakeup();
    }

    if (numRead == -1){
        activeCmeDeviceSession.disconnect(CmeDeviceSessionsClosedBy.device);
        key.cancel();
    } else if (numRead > 0) {
        raw_data = new byte[numRead];
        System.arraycopy(byteBuffer.array(), 0, raw_data, 0, numRead);

        if (activeCmeDeviceSession.getRemaining() != null && activeCmeDeviceSession.getRemaining().length > 0) {
           log.info("Remaining=" + JBBPUtils.array2hex(activeCmeDeviceSession.getRemaining()));
           raw_data = ArrayUtils.addAll(activeCmeDeviceSession.getRemaining(), raw_data);
           activeCmeDeviceSession.setRemaining(null); //svuoto il buffer dei "rimasugli"
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        CmeDevicesRecord cmeDeviceRecord;

        List<byte[]> packets = splitPacket(raw_data,(byte)(0x55),activeCmeDeviceSession);
        for (byte[] data : packets) {
            try {
               pkt = ReceiveAuthenticationRequest.PARSER.parse(data).mapTo(new ReceiveAuthenticationRequest());
               [...]                                                
               activeCmeDeviceSession.write(anser_byte_buffer);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
               log.error(ioe);
            }
        }       
    }
}
            

and this is the write method:
public int write(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, boolean enableVerboseLog) {
    int bytes = 0;      
    bytes = channel.write(byteBuffer); 
            byteBuffer.flip();      
    SelectionKey key = channel.keyFor(selector);
    if (key != null && key.isValid()) {
        key.interestOps(key.interestOps() | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE); // OP_READ
        selector.wakeup();
    }
    return (bytes);
}


thank you very much for any help in this
Cristiano
EDIT: we tried to install the same server on a Raspberry and it perfectly works. As tcpdump shows that the packets are not sent at all, this lead me to focus to a linux configuration issue...is that possible?
